# Click event interrupts submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery-events, event-bubbling

Imagine something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing event bubbling</title>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Clicked');
            return true;
        });
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Submitted');
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div><div><div>
        Click this.
        <input type="submit">
    </div></div></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when you click on the submit button, the click event is captured and propagated down to all the DIVs and you see 'Clicked' three times. Whats peculiar to me, is that this seems to skip over the form submit event. If I remove the Click binding, the submit event gets triggered correctly. Is there a way around without manually triggering submit() on the form? I know I can make the click event more specific so it doesn't apply to the submit button, but... I have a weird usecase.

What am I getting wrong here? If one event is triggered, does that mean all other events of lower priority are ignored?

Comment: why are you calling `e.preventDefault()` on click

Comment: You are binding the click event for all `DIV`s. So it is showing 3 times. Button is inside # divs. So 3 times the click event will be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault()` is used to prevent the default action of some controls. For example, if you click a link, it will try to load its `href`, if you click a submit button, it will try to submit the form. So, `preventDefault` is used to prevent those actions.

If you don't want the submit to "interrupt", in other words, if you want to submit the form, remove the `preventDefault` from your click event.

Now, second point, the click event is propagated 3 times. You have something like:

```
<div>
    Div 1
    <div>
        Div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

And you are binding the onclick method to every `<div>` on the page. So, 3 divs, 3 onclicks.
If all divs are overlapped then when you click the inner one, you are clicking it's parent div too, and so on.
You can use `stopPropagation()` if you don't want the event to propagate to deeper divs (think of it as "layers" one over each other).

Comment: Aaah... just removing e.preventDefault() fixed it. I, for some reason figured that preventDefault() only affect the current event type. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. It's a good idea to check jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ It's easy to read and there are some examples so it's the best place to start when using new jQuery functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the event bubbling to other elements. There's no need to call `e.preventDefault()` on click here - it stops the default action being executed and that's not what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the click happend in an input field

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
        e.preventDefault();
    }  
    console.log('Clicked');
    return true;
});
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Submitted');
});
```